# Azure B2C App Registration - why can't I change my redirect URI?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm moving into testing for my application and so need to move from localhost:8080 to an azure static web app. I am trying to amend my authentication redirect URI in my registered app to the new url but I can't:

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can just reproduce your issue with the wrong values in `requiredResourceAccess` in the `Manifest` of the app.

In this case, your redirect URL is valid, make sure you provide the correct values in `requiredResourceAccess`.

[image]

If you are not sure, you could remove them first -> Save.

```
"requiredResourceAccess": [
    
],
```

Secondly, modify the redirect URL -> Save, then navigate to the `API permissions` to add the permissions you want again(`requiredResourceAccess` is the mapping of `API permissions`).

Comment: Thanks Joy, I'll give this a go today.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I'm a little bit concerned about what I've deleted though - have I removed access to this app from other resources?

Comment: @JTInfinite No, it just removes the permissions you added in the `API permissions` before, if the permission was consented by the admin, the permission is still applying to the corresponding service principal, so if you want, just add them back in the `API permissions`.